# Handling a method from outside of a mixin module in ruby and rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class that looks like this:

```
module ReusableBitlyLinks
  def shorten_url url, *args
    ShortenedUrl.shorten_url_with_bitly( url, email.user )
  end
end
```

I have a test that looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path("../../../../app/decorators/mixins/reusable_bitly_links", __FILE__)

include ReusableBitlyLinks

describe ReusableBitlyLinks do

  describe "shorten_url" do
    it "works" do
      ReusableBitlyLinks.shorten_url('asdf').should == 'asdf'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test I get an error that says: 
`uninitialized constant ReusableBitlyLinks::ShortenedUrl`

How do I mock stub `ReusableBitlyLinks::ShortenedUrl`?

Answer (score 0):

Is `ShortenedUrl` defined inside `ReusableBitlyLinks` module? If not - try to access it with `::ShortenedUrl.shorten_url_with_bitly`.

Not sure what stubbing has to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

In your mixin module, you need to tell it that `ShortenedUrl` is from outside the module by prepending `::`:

```
module ReusableBitlyLinks
  def shorten_url(url, *args)
    ::ShortenedUrl.shorten_url_with_bitly(url, email.user)
  end
end
```

You may also need to do a `require` inside the mixin file to load whatever file it is that defines `ShortenedUrl`.

Further, in your test file, the line:

```
require File.expand_path("../../../../app/decorators/mixins/reusable_bitly_links", __FILE__)
```

could be simplified to:

```
require_relative '../../../../app/decorators/mixins/reusable_bitly_links'
```